Modificar GMapPanel for ExtJs4
Es posible usar este codigo con nuevas versiones de la API de google maps? funciono bien hasta la version 3.53, pero desde la 3.54 hasta la 3.57 (actual) no carga el mapa
Ext.ux.GMapPanel.superclass.initComponent.call(this);        

        if (window.google && window.google.maps){
          this.on('afterrender', this.apiReady, this);

        }else{
          window.gmapapiready = this.apiReady.createDelegate(this);
          this.buildScriptTag('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=gmapapiready');
        }

no tengo mucho conocimiento en este sistema, pero la empresa que nos armo el programa ya no existe y le tengo que meter mano, desde ya muchas gracias

Aunque no es respuesta, 2 sugerencias: 1. ChatGPT: dile que estás programando para ExtJs 4.1 y que tienes ese problema, quizás pueda resolverlo; 2. Los docs: https://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.2.1/docs/#!/api/Ext.ux.GMapPanel
